# iPhone 3.0 sdk install into device issue

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I cannot install my application into device using iphone3.0sdk, xcode give me this message:

> no launchable executable present at path

In my group window, the product folder contain the `name1.app` file, but is outlined with red color, and always remain there. Even thought I have changed my product name to `name2` the message always said that *the `name1.app` cannot be found in path*, but my current product name is supposed to be `name2.app` already.

Build on the simulator is fine, the product app file will change based on the product name but not working when install into device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go in the settings of the builder, change to "Realese", and type the same name as the one of your application.

Get back in debug mode, then clic "build and debug".

It work perfectly ;)